# How can I stop my golang loop when the input less than nine?

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, while-loop

```
var (
        value1, value2 float64
    )
for value1 < 9 || value2 < 9 || value1 < 9 && value2 < 9 {
    fmt.Print("Masukan berat belanjaan di dalam kantong : ")
    fmt.Scan(&value1, &value2)
}

fmt.Println("Program Selesai")
```

I want the program doing looping for showing input from user and stop when one of two input is less than 9. But the program always stop when both of value is more than or equals 9. Help me to fix it.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements

Answer (score 1):

> stop when one of two input is less than 9.

---

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var (
        value1, value2 float64
    )

    for {
        fmt.Print("Masukan berat belanjaan di dalam kantong : ")
        n, err := fmt.Scan(&value1, &value2)
        if n == 2 && err == nil {
            if value1 < 9 || value2 < 9 {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Program Selesai")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the sign in your code from `<` to `>`.

The conditional is backwards. It should be read as "do a for loop while value1 or value2 is greater than 9". That's when you want the for loop to execute.

If this is for a class, make sure you actually understand what's going on so you will learn.